# Assembler. Почему происходит смещение 02h

Tags: ассемблер

Очень плохо получается вкатиться в ассемблер (надо по учебе, да и интересно). С преподавателем разбираем инструкции, он задает вопросы, дает подсказки, однако все равно я не могу въехать. Уже неудобно перед учителем, так как ощущение, что он уже итак дал, что нужно.
Сейчас стоит вопрос, почему в строке  `MOV AL, msg [SI]`  эмулятор заменил метку msg на смещение 02h (см.скриншот).
А также основной вопрос - сделать скриншот, когда копируется символ L, вычислить адрес этого символа   и объяснить как.
Помогите, люди добрые.

Код:

```
JMP start
msg DB 'Hello, World!', 0
start:

;PUSH CS
;POP DS
MOV AX, 0B800h
MOV ES, AX
MOV DI, 0h
MOV SI, 0

MOV cx, 14
MOV AH, 0h

l:
MOV ES:[DI], AX
MOV AL, msg [SI]
INC AH
add DI, 2
add SI, 1

loop l



HLT
```

[image: cкрин]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Потому что первый `JMP start`, который JMP SHORT, имеет смещение 0h и длину 2, соответственно без ASSUME смещение `msg`, считаемое также в этом сегменте,  будет 2h.

Comment: Только не assume, а org. Ну и 2 тут будет или 3 зависит от самого ассемблера. Старичок tasm с одним проходом сделал бы тут троечку, например.

Comment: Если тебе действительно интересен интересно попробовать ассемблер то не порти себе впечатление  16-битным кодом, это только вызовет в тебе отвращение, попробуй 64-битный векторный ассемблер. Попробуй к примеру вычислить тригонометрические функции через ряды Тейлора на SIMD регистрах.

Comment: какое assume и org?